# Copying data to another workbook if condition/criteria is satisfied

Tags: vba, excel

sorry if this has been asked here many times. I am a beginner in vba excel, so I only have brief idea of how to begin the code. I am using Excel 2013.

I have 2 different workbooks, main and copy.
Row 1 to 4 will be empty.
Row 5 is meant for header/labeling the information it will be providing for both workbooks.

The "main" workbook will be using columns A to DN to store all the data.

If the cell contains "X" - it will copy column A to P, to the workbook "copy". After which, it will go on to the next row to determine the same thing.
If the cell is empty, it will proceed down to the next row to determine the same thing as well.
The code has to be dynamic as new information will be added every 3 months, such as new rows added or the criteria changing from "X" to empty, or empty to "X".

This is the code I have got as of now.
It works but since there are so many columns to check through, I was advised to do another code for this.

```html
Sub copy()
Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long
lr = Sheets("main").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
lr2 = Sheets("copy").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
For r = lr To 2 Step -1
    If range("Q" & r).Value = "X" Then
        Rows(r).copy Destination:=Sheets("copy").range("A" & lr2 + 1)
        lr2 = Sheets("copy").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    End If
Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: The code above is meant for copy to different sheet. But I would need to transfer it to a different workbook as of now. Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: Sorry if I am not understanding you correctly, but why would you not just filter the data, rather than looping through the data? Filter data if it meets your critieron and then paste to new sheet if the sh.range("A1000000").end(xlup).row <> 1

Answer (score 1):

For that you will have to declare two workbook variables and two worksheet variables to hold the source and destination workbooks and worksheets reference in the code.

Tweak the following code as per your requirement.

I have added the comments in the code which will help you to understand the flow of the program.

Further, more error handling can be used to make sure the source and destination sheets are found in source and destination workbook respectively.
If required, you can add the error handling as well.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyDatoToAnotherWorkbook()
Dim srcWB As Workbook, destWB As Workbook       'Variables to hold the source and destination workbook
Dim srcWS As Worksheet, destWS As Worksheet     'Variables to hold the source and destination worksheets
Dim FilePath As String                          'Variable to hold the full path of the destination workbook including it's name with extension
Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set srcWB = ThisWorkbook                        'Setting the source workbook
Set srcWS = srcWB.Sheets("main")                'Setting the source worksheet

'Setting the FilePath of the destination workbook
'The below line assumes that the destination file's name is MyFile.xlsx and it is saved at your desktop. Change the path as per your requirement
FilePath = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\MyFile.xlsx"

'Cheching if the destination file exists, it yes, proceed with the code else EXIT
If Dir(FilePath) = "" Then
    MsgBox "The file   " & FilePath & "   doesn't exist!", vbCritical, "File Not Found!"
    Exit Sub
End If
'Finding the last row used in column A on source worksheet
lr = srcWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Opening the destination workbook and setting the source workbook
Set destWB = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)

'Setting the destination worksheet
Set destWS = destWB.Sheets("copy")

'Looping through rows on source worksheets
For r = lr To 2 Step -1
    'Finding the first empty row in column A on destination worksheet
    lr2 = destWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    If srcWS.Range("Q" & r).Value = "X" Then
        srcWS.Rows(r).copy Destination:=destWS.Range("A" & lr2 + 1)
    End If
Next r

'Closing the destination workbook
destWB.Close True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```